# screen orientation fixed while imageView rotating

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like my app to keep displaying the status bar in portrait mode but need the imageView containing a picture that populate the entire screen to be affected by the accelerometer. The app forces you to hold the device in landscape mode and I want it to turn so that the arrow always points up (only two different states (See the pictures linked below for further description.))

I've tried setting the android:screenOrientation to portrait but then nothing rotates. If I choose landscape instead the statusbar is fixed in landscape and I can't have that either.

Reply is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

//wlmr

[#1. this is to show how the image is orientated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QviMV.jpg)

[#2. when held with the opposite side up it should rotate so that the arrow points up again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKYb5.jpg)